# To use Migration in ASP .NET Core, I encountered an error and I need help to fix it

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Error:

> Unable to create an object of type 'MyEshopContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time

I want to apply an option to `MyEshopContext`.

```
public class MyEshopContext : DbContext
{
    public MyEshopContext(DbContextOptions<MyEshopContext> options) : base(options) 
    { }

    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

`Program.cs`:

```
void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();

    services.AddDbContext<MyEshopContext>(optionsAction: options => { options.UseSqlServer(connectionString: ".; Initial catalog=EshopCore_DB; Integrated Security=true;"); });
}
```

I want to apply an option to `MyEshopContext`. After the `Add-Miration` command and selecting the name in the console, I encountered this error. It seems that there is a problem with changing the object and updating the database table by EF Core, but I don't know how to fix the problem